# Opening miui battery saver for specific apps

Tags: android, battery, xiaomi, miui

I am working on VoIP calling applications and calls are getting missed which are sent over FCM when battery saver is on on **MIUI**. This is happening very frequently.

I want user to open `Battery saver activity` for my own app and give no restriction for that app in battery saver.

For example: this is a the battery saver page for whatsApp. 
[image]

I want to open this page directly for my app from my app.

I have managed to enable autostart in the shown way. [How to check MIUI autostart permission programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39366565/3467146)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

After checking logs for the MiFit app, I finally figured it out!

It took almost 3 days of continuous research. *Pheww, here is the code.*

```
try {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(ComponentName("com.miui.powerkeeper", "com.miui.powerkeeper.ui.HiddenAppsConfigActivity"));
        intent.putExtra("package_name", getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra("package_label", getText(R.string.app_name));
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    }
```

Comment: perfect answer! Thanks for all.

Comment: what if I want to check the battery saver status for my app, whether it's restricted, unrestricted, ...etc?

Comment: @SamerAlkhatib I didn't find any official way yet. But you can put an internal check after 2nd opening if the last opening time is greater than your desired timespan, show the turn-on batter saver alert.